# Сравнение чисел в массиве java

Tags: java, массивы

Задача: Создать массив из 4 случайных чисел. Вывести их на экран, и с новой строки вывести сообщение о том, какая это последовательность (возрастающая, убывающая или же никакая).

Вот мой код:

```
public class four {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] mas = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            Random ran = new Random();
            mas[i] = ran.nextInt(90) + 10;
            System.out.print(mas[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        if (mas[0] < mas[1] & mas[1] < mas[2] & mas[2] < mas[3]) {
            System.out.println("Последовательность строго возрастающая");
        } else if (mas[0] > mas[1] & mas[1] > mas[2] & mas[2] > mas[3]) {
            System.out.println("Последовательность строго убывающая");
        } else
            System.out.println("Другая последовательность");
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли по другому сделать данную задачу? Например уже не из 4-х чисел, а допустим 50 или же 100.

Comment: Если у вас будет массив из 50-ти рандомных чисел, то я сомневаюсь, что там будет убывающая или возрастающая последовательность)))  И у вас в условии побитовая операция, кмк, а не логическая

Comment: Да)) Это то так, но все же хотелось узнать как можно сделать такую же задачу с помощью цикла.

Comment: Там даже циклы не нужны

Comment: Можно как нибудь через цикл сделать или нет?

Comment: .......Можно)))

Comment: А не подскажете?? Пожалуйста!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так. Дальше уже не трудно методы дёрнуть.

```
int[] generateSequesce(int length, int maxValue, int minValue){
    Random ran = new Random();
    int[] result = new int[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
        result[i] = ran.nextInt(maxValue-minValue) + minValue;
    }
    return result;
}

boolean isIncreasing(int[] sequence){
    int lastValue = sequence[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < sequence.length; i++){
        if (lastValue < sequence[i]){
            lastValue = sequence[i];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean isDecreasing(int[] sequence){
    int lastValue = sequence[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < sequence.length; i++){
        if (lastValue > sequence[i]){
            lastValue = sequence[i];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую)